# How to disable an specific feature of ReSharper 5.x

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I'm use ReSharper 5.x which have a feature when i hold Ctrl and hover mouse over Class or methods (Or anything into codes), an underline is shown and when i click, ReSharper automatically opens code-file of that class or method (Function exactly like Go to Reference in Visual Studio code files context menu item).

How i can disable this feature, I can't find any option for this in Options dialog? and what's name of this feature?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to disable this feature?

Comment: Because **I do not like this feature**

Comment: ctrl+click defaults to "highlight full word" and is much faster than double-click when doing rapid copy & paste operations, as you never need to let go of ctrl.

Comment: I agree. I hate that "feature". Glad it's gone now :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well, if you absolutely don't want to have the feature enabled, can disable it by doing:

1. ReSharper menu -> Options
2. Search & Navigation (4th from the top)
3. Uncheck "Go to Declaration on <Control + Left Click> in editor